# Why INT_MAX minus INT_MIN equals -1?

Tags: c++

As [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) suggested, `INT_MAX = 32767` and `INT_MIN = -32767` so `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` should equal to 65534, however it gives me -1;

I'm confused because 65534 does not overflow the limit of int in C++ and even I assign the value in a long long int, it still gave me -1. I think may be I misunderstand some mechanism about C++ reduction. Anyone no what's exactly going on when `INT_MAX` minus `INT_MIN`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The page says "or less" / "or greater". Also, **if** 32767 really **was** the value of `INT_MAX`, that means it **does** overflow for 65534.

Comment: You think `65534` does not overflow `int` on implementations where `INT_MAX` is `32767`?

Comment: if you say INT_MAX = 32767 on some implementation, of course even 32768 overflows

Comment: Also, assigning the result to `long long int` doesn't change the overflow of the computation, which is done in type `int`. You need to cast the operands to `long long int` to see a change: `long long int(INT_MAX) - long long int(INT_MIN)`

Comment: If you subtract a negative number from the maximum positive value, overflow is guaranteed. Right? Whatever you do with the answer (whether storing it in a `long long int` or something else), you will be doing something with a value that resulted from an overflow.

Comment: @hvd what I meant was the greatest value that a 16 bit int can represent is 65535 and apparently 65534 is smaller than this value.

Comment: @ODStreet "what I meant was the greatest value that a 16 bit int can represent is 65535" -- A 16 bit int has 1 sign bit and 15 value bits. 15 value bits gives you a maximum value of `32767`. That's why `INT_MAX` is `32767` as you already indicate in your question rather than `65535`.

Comment: " INT_MAX - INT_MIN should equal to 65534, however it gives me -1;"  --> would like to see the code that did that.  I would suspect code _added_ the values and resulted in -1, not subtracted.

Comment: @chux: adding or subtracting `INT_MIN` are the same thing with wraparound 2's complement arithmetic, since in that case `INT_MIN` is exactly half the modulus.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Fair point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`INT_MAX` is only equal to 32767 if you're on a compiler whose `int` type is actually 16 bits wide. Such a value for `INT_MAX` is still seen nowadays in compilers for embedded processors.

Whatever `INT_MAX` is, it is both a *value* of type `int`, and it is the maximum value of that type. If, in the `int` type, you subtract the most negative `int` value from the most positive one, you're triggering overflow, which is **undefined behavior**.

It doesn't matter whether your `int` is 16 bits wide, or 64; the calculation expressed by `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` doesn't have a well-defined meaning according to ISO C.

It's possible that the -1 result is defined by your implementation.  Namely that your compiler adheres to specific rules about integer overflow. Check your compiler manual.

The subtraction could be performed if a type is available which is wider than `int`. For instance, suppose that `long long` is wider than `int` on some given compiler. (This is not required, but suppose we have an implementation where it's true, which is common). Then we can do:

```
(long long) INT_MAX - (long long) INT_MIN
```

There is no overflow now because the calculation is carried out in the wider type. We obtain the arithmetically correct value. That value won't fit back into type `int`, of course.

---

Now a hypothesis about the -1, keeping in in mind that it could just be a fluke and not defined by your compiler at all.

Suppose that you have a compiler for a two's complement machine which defines the behavior for signed overflow as having simple "wrapping" semantics. The -1 value can then be explained as follows. Suppose `INT_MIN` is the most negative two's complement value, represented by `1000..0000` in binary. `INT_MAX` is `0111..1111`. The calculation `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` then subtracts these two.  Not much interesting happens in the lower bits, because a sequence of `0`'s is being subtracted from a sequence of `1`'s. Then, the subtraction reaches the upper bits: `0 - 1`.  This results in the value `1`, with a borrow out ("borrow" is the subtraction's counterpart to addition's "carry"). The borrow is discarded, and we are just left with the truncated result `1111...1111`.  That of course is the two's complement representation of -1.

Note that `INT_MIN` could also be defined simply as `-INT_MAX`, which is the binary value `1000...0001`. In that case, the same wrapping arithmetic will produce the result -2, perhaps more surprising than -1.

So why you're seeing -1 is probably that you're getting two's complement wrapping behavior, plus the fact that `INT_MIN` is not actually the arithmetic inverse of `INT_MAX` (which would call for a -2 result), but a value which is one less than that.

Comment: 100s of millions of embedded processors per year in 2015 use 16-bit `int` - not that rare.  Yet your overall point is correct.  OTOH - these are more likely using C code, so I guess C++ is closer to your assertion.

Comment: Fabulous answer with nice explanation of how subtraction work, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you say `INT_MAX = 32767` on some implementation, of course even 32768 overflows.

Besides notice that if you are adding two integer literals say `int + int` even if you assign that result to `long` (assuming long can hold result of that addition), that doesn't help, since overflow could have happened when `int` was added with `int` - because the result of addition didn't fit inside an `int`; the compiler doesn't promote `int` to `long` in this case based on the fact that the result of addition doesn't fit inside `int`.

Answer (score 1):

> INT_MAX = 32767 and INT_MIN = -32767

Actually they are:

-32767 (-2^15+1) **or less***

32767 (2^15-1) **or greater***

I'm almost shure that on your system, sizeof(int)==4 -> 4 bytes -> **32** bit.

And INT_MAX is defined as 2^**32**-1 == 4294967295.

Apply same for INT_MIN.

Type smth like:

```
std::cout << INT_MAX << " " << INT_MIN << std::endl;
```

and you will see.
There is actually an **overflow** in int(INT_MAX-INT_MIN), so **it is -1**.

Answer (score 1):

That page says nothing of the sort. It says that `INT_MAX` is at least 32767. It doesn't say it's equal. If you want to know the actual value on a particular implementation, print it out (or look at that implementation's documentation, bearing in mind that it may depend on the architecture targeted).

Anyway, the definition of `INT_MAX` is the largest value of `int`, so `INT_MAX+1` is enough to overflow the limit of `int`, never mind `INT_MAX - INT_MIN`. The value of `-1` that you obtained is implementation-specific behaviour, but it's not an *unexpected* result from a typical 2's complement implementation, in which `INT_MAX` will be equal to 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1 and `INT_MIN` will be equal to -2<sup>N-1</sup>, for some value N referred to as the "width" of `int` in bits. This is most commonly[*] 32, but is permitted by the standard to be as low as 16. So the actual values are `2147483647` and `-2147483648` for an implementation with a 32 bit 2's complement `int`, and `32767` and `-32768` for an implementation with a 16 bit 2's complement `int`.

On such an implementation, and *supposing that integer overflow wraps around*, then the result of `INT_MAX - INT_MIN` would be `-1` as you saw, since the mathematical value is 2<sup>N</sup>-1, which is -1 modulo 2<sup>N</sup>. For example, GCC has an option `-fwrapv` you can use if you want to ensure that integer overflow wraps, and if you don't specify that option then it might wrap or it might do something different.

[*] by some very unscientific notion of "most common".